# Confusion about distributed cache in Hadoop

Tags: caching, hadoop, hive, distributed-cache

What does the distribute cache actually mean? Having a file in distributed cache means that is it available in every datanode and hence there will be no internode communication for that data, or does it mean that the file is in memory in every node?
If not, by what means can I have a file in memory for the entire job? Can this be done both for map-reduce, as well as for a UDF..

(In particular there is some configuration data, comparatively small that I would like to keep in memory as a UDF applies on hive query...? )

Thanks and regards,
Dhruv Kapur.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

DistributedCache is a facility provided by the Map-Reduce framework to cache files needed by applications. Once you cache a file for your job, hadoop framework will make it available on each and every data nodes (in file system, not in memory) where you map/reduce tasks are running. Then you can access the cache file as local file in your Mapper Or Reducer job. Now you can easily read the cache file and populate some collection (e.g Array, Hashmap etc.) in your code.

Refer https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html

Let me know if still you have some questions.

You can read the cache file as local file in your UDF code. After reading the file using JAVA APIs just populate any collection (In memory).

Refere URL http://www.lichun.cc/blog/2013/06/use-a-lookup-hashmap-in-hive-script/

-Ashish

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply... So I am more concerned about when and how do we put something from distributed cache into memory? In case of Hive, I'll need access to this file in the distributed cache inside a UDF. How do I get it there? I should not be reading a HDFS file from inside a UDF right?

Comment: I've modified the post. Just refer the mentioned URL.

Comment: That's exactly what I am searching for. Thanks! I am still a little concerned if the map inside the UDF is only populated once or not. Is there some documentation of hive supporting this, or some way that I can verify this behavior?

Comment: Distributed cache concept works in very same way for all hadoop map-reduce, pig, hive etc. In your mapper/reducer function just populate a collection before iterating records to process. In this way you map populates only once for a map/reduce task.

Comment: Are these files read only? Can they be modified by any of the mappers or reducers?

Comment: These files can be treated as any local files (need to check for the write permission). But why do you want to modify. What's your use-case?

Comment: After adding a file, I am trying to access it in my UDF  but is failing with file not found. If I run list command on hive shell than I am able to get it under - "mnt/tmp/<A long string>resource/" dir but UDF is expecting at - "/user/hadoop". I am using EMR. Am I missing something ?

Comment: First link is Broken

Comment: Updated the post for new link